# Flutter: placing CircularProgressIndicator() widget while using 'firebase_image' package

Tags: flutter

I am using `firebase_image` package and trying to use the `CircularProgressIndicator()` widget while the image is loading up.

I've been trying like `FadeInImages` with `transparent_time` package to do it. However, since this is the not the link. It was not possible to place it.

```
Image(
              image: FirebaseImage(
                  'gs://chichichi.appspot.com/someimage.jpg'),
              // Works with standard parameters, e.g.
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              width: Get.width,
            ),
```

The best apporach I have is to have the `CircularProgressIndi` widget to be stacked down to the `FirebaseImage()` widget. I do not think this will be the appropriate solution.

Is there any way that I can place the `CircularProgressIndicator()` in this situation? Or, do I just have to use the standard package to download the image from Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [loadingBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/loadingBuilder.html), something like this:

```
Image(
...
  loadingBuilder: (_, child, loadingProgress) {
    if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  } 
)
```